# How does Adobe target obfuscates IPs?

Tags: ipv4, adobe-analytics

I have a dataset containing obfuscated IPs. In order to do something, I would need to match IPs I know with this dataset.

If my dataset contains hashed IPs `1053617334`, `1043615471`

And I have IP `192.168.0.1`, how can I hash it so I can verify if it is in the dataset or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPv4 addresses are commonly represented as so-called "dotted quads", like `192.0.2.42` or `192.168.0.1`.

That's 32 bits of data. And, that same data can be represented as a single unsigned decimal number.  Your numbers like `1053617334`, `1043615471` are probably examples of those numbers. They aren't, strictly speaking, hashed or obfuscated. They're just represented differently.

`http://192.168.0.1` and `http://3232235521` mean exactly the same thing.

There are all sorts of online tools to convert back and forth between dotted quad and decimal representation.  [For example](https://www.browserling.com/tools/dec-to-ip).

Consult your AA documentation or support team to figure out how to handle this.